# DeepSpeed will not properly install and keeps failing, I have torch installed

Tags: pytorch, torch

```
C:\Users\19134>pip install deepspeed
Collecting deepspeed
  Using cached deepspeed-0.9.2.tar.gz (779 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [20 lines of output]
      [WARNING] Unable to import torch, pre-compiling ops will be disabled. Please visit https://pytorch.org/ to see how to properly install torch on your system.
      ←[93m [WARNING] ←[0m unable to import torch, please install it if you want to pre-compile any deepspeed ops.
      DS_BUILD_OPS=1
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\19134\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\19134\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "C:\Users\19134\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "C:\Users\19134\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-890dpy90\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 341, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
        File "C:\Users\19134\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-890dpy90\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 323, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\19134\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-890dpy90\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 487, in run_setup
          super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
        File "C:\Users\19134\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-890dpy90\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 338, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 128, in <module>
      AssertionError: Unable to pre-compile ops without torch installed. Please install torch before attempting to pre-compile ops.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I have torch installed and it appears it wants me to install it again?
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, so the error says there's an issue with the PyTorch installation, try uninstalling it and reinstalling it.

Test the version:

```
import torch
print(torch.__version__)
```

**IMPORTANT:** *This is copied and pasted from DeepSpeed as well:*
"PyTorch must be installed before installing DeepSpeed. For full feature support we recommend a version of PyTorch that is >= 1.9 and ideally the latest PyTorch stable release."